# Word splitting when using cut if delimiter are multiple spaces

Tags: bash, debian, cut

I am running a bash script doing following:

```
cut -d ' ' -f2 <<< "aaa bbb"
```

Getting as a result:

```
bbb
```

In case there is more than one space as delimiter (let's say three):

```
cut -d ' ' -f2 <<< "aaa   bbb"
```

Result is:

```
 bbb
```

This is running under debian 8.

Now, the very same script just running under debian 10 produces a different output:

In case there is more than one space as delimiter (let's say three):

```
cut -d ' ' -f2 <<< "aaa   bbb"
```

The result is " ", just a white space.

I would like to have same behavior in debian 8 as in debian 10.
Any ideas?

(I know, I could just use tr -s and get rid of the three spaces, but I want to understand why is there a different behavior).

Best regards,
Zos

Comment: I would consider the behavior you describe with Debian 8 as a bug. `cut` doesn't handle succcessive separators as one (awk does though, consider `awk '{print $2}' <<< "aaa   bbb"` as a portable workaround), so it looks like they fixed a bug in a newer release. Can you add the output of `cut -V` on each of the two systems?

Comment: @terdon, I tested that with `cut` from coreutils 8.4 (some way too old machine), 8.23 (Debian 8), 8.26 (Debian 9) and 8.30 (Ubuntu 20.04), and some versions of busybox, and I can't see the behaviour described here.

Comment: `string="aaa   bbb"; echo $string | cut -d ' ' -f2;`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the behaviour of `cut` should have changed like that so recently. I also can't reproduce that with Debian 8.11 and `cut` from GNU coreutils 8.23.

However, if you give `cut` the argument `-f 2-`, with the trailing dash, you'll get all fields starting at field 2. Which I suppose pretty much matches what you describe:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f2- <<< "aaa   bbb"
  bbb
```

Note that there's two leading spaces in the output, they're the field delimiters between fields 2 (empty), 3 (empty), and 4 (`bbb`). You had one leading space in the question, but I don't know if that was on purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I've created [a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00001.html) that adds new `-m` command-line option to `cut`, which works in the field mode and treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  This basically solves the OP's question in a rather efficient way.  I also submitted this patch upstream a couple of days ago, and let's hope that it will be merged into the coreutils project.

There are some [further thoughts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00011.html) about adding even more whitespace-related features to `cut`, and having some feedback about all that would be great.  I'm willing to implement more patches for `cut` and submit them upstream, which would make this utility more versatile and more usable in various real-world scenarios.